# Apache virtual host

Tags: apache, virtual, host

i have been struck on this for a looooong time now :-(,  Basically my "Alias" tag is not working in my c:\xampp\apache\conf\virtual-hosts.conf. Url http://raghu.tkiportal works OK but http://raghu.tkiportal/simplesaml DOES NOT. The directory structure for Alias tag exists in my localhost (i checked)

This is my setting for one of many sites

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>   
AcceptPathInfo On
ServerName raghu.tkiportal
Alias /simplesaml C:/xampp/htdocs/tki_portal4.2/extension/feide/lib/simplesaml/www
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/tki_portal4.2

<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/tki_portal4.2>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>



LogLevel debug
ErrorLog C:/xampp/apache/logs/raghu_tki_portal_error.log
CustomLog C:/xampp/apache/logs/raghu_tki_portal_access.log combined
ServerSignature On
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^/var/([^/]+/)?storage/images(-versioned)?/.*  /index_image_tki_portal.php [L]

RewriteRule !(^/design|^/var|.*/storage|^/var/storage|^/var/.*/cache|^/var/cache|^/extension/.*/design|^/kernel/setup/packages|^/packages|^/share/icons).*\.(gif|css|jpg|png|jar|js|ico|pdf|swf|mov|html|xml|xsl|htc)$ /index.php

</VirtualHost>
```

Do you guys see any fault with my settings? The same setting works on linux box.

Any help would be very much appreciated...Thanks guys

RD

Answer (score 3):

Try this (as Windows uses \ instead of / in path names):

```
Alias /simplesaml C:\xampp\htdocs\tki_portal4.2\extension\feide\lib\simplesaml\www
DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\tki_portal4.2
```

I haven't run Apache on Windows before but think that the / in the paths are the issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply karudzo...just tried that but did not work :-(

Comment: Did you change it in the <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/tki_portal4.2> are to <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\tki_portal4.2> (I forgot to mention it)?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like my answer is off the mark then.  It looks like Apache deals internally with the "/" to "\" issue prior to passing off to the file system part of Windows.

Comment: yep have changed that also karudzo. Interestingly if i copy and paste the Alias line from virtua-host.conf to httpd.conf, it works for the URL http://localhost/simplesaml...its just not working for http://raghu.tkiportl/simlesaml :-(

Answer (score 1):

is http://raghu.tkiportal/extension/feide/lib/simplesaml/www working?

Then reading your configuration I'm afraid the last rewrite rule takes precedence on your alias (or applies just after). So your /simplesaml/index.[html.php] is redirected on /index.php

The rewrite rule contains exceptions, try to add simplesaml in the exceptions listing:

```
RewriteRule !(^/simplesaml|^/design|^/var|.* ...
```

To debug this you could activate RewriteLogLevel 9 and a Rewrite Log /absolute/path/to/debug.log and check that you calls on /simplesaml are rewritten by mod_rewrite

Comment: [SOLVED] I had to include a RewriteCond...saying if its simplesaml then don't apply the the last rewrite rule. thanks for the tip regilero regarding the RewriteRule.

Comment: so choose the response, or upvote, and for people coming here via google post your final fix please

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I had to include a RewriteCond...saying if its simplesaml then don't apply the the last rewrite rule. thanks for the tip regilero regarding the RewriteRule.